# Java Server PHP client on Raspberry Pi issues

Tags: java, php, sockets, raspberry-pi

I am working on some simple home automation stuff using the Raspberry Pi. On the Pi I have a Java server running that can interact with the GPIO pins based on the commands it receives. I then plan on creating a web interface using jQuery and PHP to interface with the Java server. The user can click a button on the web page and that request will be processed with PHP, which will make a connection to the Java server via a socket. The PHP will write the command to the Java server based on the user's input.

The issue I am having here is that my PHP code that is running on an Apache sever located on the Pi will not connect to the Java socket. I keep getting an "unable to connect[110] connection timed out" error. With the Java server running on the Pi, I can connect to the server with a Java client from another machine and I can also connect to the Java server via PHP running on my laptop (note the client PHP code I ran was the same on both machines).

This leads me to believe that the issue lies with PHP running on the Pi itself. Are there some settings involving permissions or something of the like that would be preventing me from being able to connect to the Java server form PHP on the Pi?

I can't seem to find anything out there to suggest what my problem is. As I said I believe that the issue lies in the PHP engine itself that is running on the Pi. I have no idea what settings may be causing this issue. I'm not going to post any code because I have confirmed that it in fact performs as intended.

Here is the Java Server that is running on the Raspberry Pi.

```
ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(20222);
     System.out.println("Server listening for connections");
     while(true)
     {
        Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("Client Has Connected");

         BufferedReader input =
           new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
           clientCommand = input.readLine();
     }
```

The PHP client that is running on the Pi. FYI the Pi's local address is `10.0.0.27` I have tried changing the `$HOST` variable to `localhost` and `0.0.0.0` all with no effect.

```
 $PORT = 20222; //the port on which we are connecting to the "remote" machine
 $HOST = "10.0.0.27"; //the ip of the remote machine (in this case it's the same machine)

 $sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) //Creating a TCP socket
        or die("error: could not create socket\n");
 $succ = socket_connect($sock, $HOST, $PORT) //Connecting to to server using that socket
         or die("error: could not connect to host\n");

 $text = "Hello, Java!"; //the text we want to send to the server
 echo "Connected to Server...";
 socket_write($sock, "test" . "\n", strlen($text) + 1) //Writing the text to the socket
         or die("error: failed to write to socket\n");
```

After running the Java server and doing a `sudo netstat -tnlp` I get this output.
`pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo netstat -tlnp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2427/sshd

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:20222           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29175/java

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5900            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2508/Xtightvnc

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5901            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2463/Xtightvnc

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2508/Xtightvnc

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2208/apache2

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2463/Xtightvnc`

When the PHP client on the Pi tries to connect, it will just timeout and won't connect. If I run the same PHP client on my laptop which is on the same network as the pi, and just change the `$HOST` variable to the Pi's address I can connect with no issues and write to the TCP socket. It seems that the Java server is working and listening as it should. I appress to be an issue with the php running on the Pi.

Comment: PHP is on the same device as the Java server, right? Have you tried connecting using PHP on the console? If it is a simple GET method, could you try `wget` or `curl` from the console?

Comment: Just check if your raspberrypi IP address is locally resolvable. If you have used fixed IP in PHP code at raspberrypi, try replacing it with localhost or 127.0.0.1 and try again.

Comment: Yes PHP and the Java server are both running on the Pi. I am trying to connect to the Java server using sockets. The PHP client will not connect to the Java's server socket.                                                              I've tried changing the address that the PHP socket is trying to connect to... I've tried "localhost" "127.0.0.1" and the Pi's local IP address. I was able to connect to the Java' server socket using another Java client connecting to either of the above addresses. This leads me to believe its a setting in PHP itself that is not allowing the connection

Comment: First let's figure out what your java server is exposing. Can you please `sudo netstat -tlnp` which should show all open listening sockets and name of the corresponding process. Can you please paste this info as update to your post? FYI `sudo` is necessary to resolve names of the processes. Without it it will just show listening ports.

Second, what kind of request are you sending to the server? Is it HTTP request? or you're sending plain text commands via socket?

Comment: Well, now try to connect to java server directly from command line by typing `telnet 127.0.0.1 20222` and see if you get though. If you manage to connect successfully you will get messages like `
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.` and then you can type `test<ENTER>` to see if your server picks up `readLine()` and spits something out to you

Comment: And you can try also `telnet 10.0.0.27 20222` just to be sure there's no surprises. And if they don't work, try dumping your network config via `ifconfig -a` and paste it here. :)

Comment: telnet will not connect to the Java Server, the connection times out. I've tried using `telnet 127.0.0.1 20222` , `telnet localhost 20222` and `telnet 10.0.0.271 20222` all of which timed out. What is interesting is that when I run a Java Client program on the Pi and connect it to the Server's socket at `10.0.0.27 20222` it connects fine. This has me completely stumped...

Comment: here is my ifconfig `pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ifconfig -a
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0f:55:a8:c7:e4  
          inet addr:10.0.0.27  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6983 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3554 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:7389019 (7.0 MiB)  TX bytes:386523 (377.4 KiB)` The other ports are not active... Thanks for the help @DimitryK!!

Comment: Very strange... :S try this blind shot `telnet ::1 20222`